# When adding UIView instantiated with an .xib to the Storyboard buttons don't work and background color can't be changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiview

I am working on an iOS project and wanted to include a UIView that is reused on multiple screens in the application (appearing at the bottom of different UIViews). I am using a storyboard for the UI work so far but created an .xib file to be used by the reusable view (playerView in code below).

The view gets added but the button I have added to the View is unresponsive, also my background color cannot be changed on the view. I have tried to set background color programmatically and in the .xib with no luck. Very weird symptoms and I tried to instantiate the view from #5 of [this article](http://eppz.eu/blog/uiview-from-xib/) and probably did something wrong. I dont fully understand everything in the article which makes me nervous - for instance my showSubclassedView method returns IBAction but I just call the function name in code and dont use a button (I did hook up the buttons in the view as the article described though).

Here is the code:

EventViewController.m      (where I trry and add PlayerView)

```
#import "EventViewController.h"
#import "PlayerView.h"

@interface EventViewController ()
-(IBAction)showSubclassedView;
@end

@implementation EventViewController


-(IBAction)showSubclassedView
{
    [PlayerView presentInViewController:self];
}
```

PlayerView.h        (.h for reusable view)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Utils.h"

@class PlayerView;

@protocol PlayerViewDelegate
-(void)playerViewTouchedUp:(PlayerView*) playerView;
-(void)playerViewDidDismiss:(PlayerView*) playerView;
@end

@interface PlayerView : UIView

+(void)presentInViewController:(UIViewController<PlayerViewDelegate>*) playerView;
-(IBAction)viewTouchedUp;
-(IBAction)dismiss;

 @end
```

PlayerView.m              (.m for reusable view)

```
#import "PlayerView.h"

@interface PlayerViewOwner : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet PlayerView *playerView;
@end

@implementation PlayerViewOwner
@end

@interface PlayerView ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController <PlayerViewDelegate> *delegateViewController;
@end

@implementation PlayerView

+(void)presentInViewController:(UIViewController<PlayerViewDelegate> *)viewController
{
    PlayerViewOwner *owner = [PlayerViewOwner new];
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass(self) owner:owner options:nil];
    owner.playerView.delegateViewController = viewController;

    [viewController.view addSubview:owner.playerView];
}

-(IBAction)viewTouchedUp
{
    //forward to delegate
    NSLog(@"you clicked a button");
    [self.delegateViewController playerViewTouchedUp:self];
}

-(IBAction)dismiss
{
    [self removeFromSuperview];

    // Forward to delegate
    [self.delegateViewController playerViewDidDismiss:self];
}

@end
```

PlayerView.xib has a UIbutton on it that connects it to viewTouchedUp method in PLayerView.m

Is there anything I did wrong in the code above? Is this the best way to do a reusable view to display on other views?

Thank you!

Comment: great article. the author provides a link to their repo for the project, have you checked that out? But, a couple of things: ensure user interaction is enabled for the button (presumably you're not even seeing the NSLog), show where in your code you are changing the color of the view, and also inspect the buttons' connections and make sure you haven't added extra connections that would be interfering. As for the use of `IBAction`, I believe it's handled the same as `void` but gives a hint to the program that interface builder is involved.. but you should still use `void` in this case

Comment: I have changed the IBAction to void, good to do but you're right it didn't change anything. I dont see any other connections that are out of place but I will go through the authors posted code in Xcode to see. 

I wasn't programmatically changing the background color but was changing it in the PlayerView.xib, I should have mentioned that.

And yes, The NSLog doesnt even hit although the checkbox for enable user interaction is checked.

Ill have a go at the authors github repo tonight and report back if I discover anything.

Comment: I checked out the authors github repo and couldnt change the background their either! I found a different method which still have nice separation (not as nice) but works at least.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround I found after not being able to solve this.

[New implementation is from this article](http://onedayitwillmake.com/blog/2013/07/ios-creating-reusable-uiviews-with-storyboard/)

I reverted my changes from my initial question and implemented this. It lacks the nice protocol separation for talking back and forth and I might need something like this later but I think now I can still implement a protocol to solve this.

At least with this solution I have usable items in my view and a background that changes!